# Includes with inheritance in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, include

I'm almost finished with my BST and AVL implementations. I originally built my AVL class declaration and implementation alongside the BST just for simplicity. The AVL class inherits from the BST and this is where my problem comes in. I want, for organizational purposes to split up the AVL and BST implementations into 5 files;

bst.cpp, bst.h, avl.cpp, avl.h, driver.cpp

How should the #includes be in these files? I'm confused about how the inheritance of AVL from BST affects this relationship.

Thanks!

Comment: You should have the `#include` statements you need, and no more. Without more information, we cannot give you a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your avl.h you have to include bst.h

Within your avl.h you have to inherit from BST by simply declaring class:

`class AVL: public BST`

Comment: This. Also make sure that when you include avl.h you don't include bst.h - this could cause problems as bst.h is included from inside avl.h.

Comment: @demize: Not an issue if you properly use include guards.

Comment: @SarpKaya Your answer says to include bst.h inside avl.h.

Comment: @aschepler True, which is definitely the preferable method.

Comment: @demize sorry misunderstood your comment. adding `#ifndef bst_h` to the avl.h should protect what you have said